# generate random number between pi/2 and -pi/2

Tags: ios, math

Can someone provide a way to produce a random float between -Pi/2 and Pi/2 please?

I've tried...

```
float angleR = M_PI / arc4random_uniform(1000) - M_PI * 0.5;
```

But that doesn't work, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float angle = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*PI - PI/2;
```

You can easily adapt it to use `arc4rand` function (mind that its maximum value should be `0x100000000`).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. If you want your result to be (roughly) uniformly random, you certainly don't want to divide by a uniformly random number (as that will bias you severely toward angles near, in your case, -π/2).

```
float angleR = ((float)arc4random_uniform(1000) - 500) * M_PI;
```

Comment: Thanks, you were exactly right. All my "random" values were almost exactly -Pi / 2 LOL! Thanks